# Overriding a Jenkinsfile's default password parameter

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, elvis-operator

I have declarative parametrized pipeline from SCM, something like this:

```
parameters {
    string(name: 'USER', defaultValue: params.USER ?:'default_value', trim: true)
    password(name: 'PASSWORD', defaultValue: params.PASSWORD ?:'default_value')
< ... and bunch of params more ... >
}
```

Idea is to use same Jenkinsfile for several environments/projects, and override those values manually in UI accordingly. If there's a value defined already - skip it during the next build.

`string` parameter does exactly what I want, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59844206/10298825).

Problem is that Elvis operator `?:` acts strange with `password` parameter type.
It basically erases existing password value on first build if it finds it there. If I try a second build (when password is already erased during previous build), then it provides default value. And over and over…

Does anybody have any idea why that works for `string` parameter but not for `password` parameter, and how to override that issue? Except creating password parameter manually in UI, and kicking it out from Jenkinsfile, of course.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use rebuild [link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/rebuild-plugin/tree/master) button/plugin with enabled "Remember Password Enabled" in jenkins global security

what are you trying to do was removed from jenkins because of security reasons

https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisory/2022-02-15/#SECURITY-2443